# verify search working proprly using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am beginner for Selenium, just I want to check that search of the website working properly. Means when I enter any keyword in the search box and click on search is it provides correct search result. How to Check using Selenium WebDriver. Please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The site's meant for programming problems, not for posting a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. It'd help if you tell us what you've tried, what specific bit you're stuck with, and what you've tried to do to solve those problems. To start you could use the search function on SO and check if someone posted a similar question.

Comment: please suggest mi the way , so  I can catch the search result and  verify  by using equals functions. I don't have  any idea how to locate  that result

Comment: java.util.List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#rhscol"));

      // Finally, we'll loop over the list to verify each result link contains our term
      for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
          Assert.assertTrue(results.get(i).getText().contains(searchTerm));
      }

Comment: i have tried this but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details about your query 
for example you should include the URL your are working on or a similar URL for the one you are working on

Comment: Dr.get("http://www.conns.com/");

  String URL = Dr.getCurrentUrl();
  WebElement ele =Dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search']"));
  ele.sendKeys("furniture");
  ele.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
 
java.util.List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("html/body/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[4]"));

Comment: mohamed faisal: The above is not an answer. It should be written in Comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an item property from the search result page as an assertion point for your test

Try below code

```
package StackOverFlow.StackOverFlow;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class App 
{
    @Test
    public void test () throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Chrome\\2\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver Dr = new ChromeDriver();
    Dr.manage().window().maximize();
    Dr.get("http://www.conns.com");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    WebElement ele = Dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search']")); 
    ele.sendKeys("furniture");
    ele.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    String result= Dr.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h1")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("Furniture & Mattresses", result);

}
}
```

I used a very obvious element (Furniture & Mattresses) on the page to assert against its text